# How do I execute hours long SQL script from my .NET API?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure

I am working on a Blazor application that enables users to upload SQL scripts and execute them on Azure databases. The .sql files are uploaded to an Azure Blob Storage and then retrieved by the .NET GraphQL API to be executed.

However those scripts are very long and intricate and take in general an hour to complete. Is using threading and async enough or should I use an Azure tool?

I am currently trying to execute the scripts directly from the C# code in asynchronous methods.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<string?> ExecuteSqlScript(BrioDBContext dbContext, string scriptName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Get GetSQLScriptContent");
        var script = await GetSQLScriptContent(scriptName, cancellationToken);

        _logger.LogInformation("Get Create Command and execute reader");
        await using var command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = script;
        await dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            await using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
            // Process the query results
            var textOutput = await SqlResultHelper.FormatResultsToJsonAsync(reader);

            // Access the text output
            Console.WriteLine(textOutput);

            // Returns the text output
            return textOutput;
        }
        finally
        {
            await dbContext.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Error @ Method:{methodName}", LoggingHelper.GetMethodName());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the scripts doing that take so long?  Do you have an example?

Comment: Please share your code and script which you have tried.

Comment: I added the code to the question. I don't have any exemple of scripts but they are updates to client DBs that are around 10gb in size for my company.